# Translation; "出来混的，迟早要还的"

Tags: translation

What's a good translation for:

> 出来混的, 迟早要还的

What comes around, goes around?

Comment: "还" (repay) refers to both "guilt you committed" and "favors other people did for you".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say your *"What comes around, goes around."* is a good translation. Another idiom you can use is *"You reap what you sow."* The only small drawback with both is that they don't necessarily imply suffering justice/reprisal for criminal activity, as the Chinese phrase does. I say *small* drawback however, because with context that shouldn't generally be a problem.

A non-idiomatic translation could be: "When you lead a life of crime, sooner or later you have to pay your debts."

Answer (score 0):

Guilt will be punished sooner or later.

Comment: I cannot see why there is a -1.